# Rigify FBX animation export twitching

Tags: rigging, export, unity, .fbx, rigify

i have some problems with exported FBX animations. I'm create armature for character using **Rigify addon** and for **Unity** I use RigifyToUnity addon. I made a few animations and after try to Export FBX, but the animations are broken.

Here is an example [before (.Blend)](https://streamable.com/u5ffjn) and [after (FBX)](https://streamable.com/qbv0d9) export. *In Unity it looks like* [image].

And I try to use **Flat Hierarchy**
(unparent all bones), the results before and after the export look just like [this](https://streamable.com/u5ffjn). *In Unity i have*[image].

I guess this is because the Unity needs child and parent relationships.

Also i tried to use **Disconnected bones**, before export everything seems to be fine, but after everything breaks down, as in the first case.

This is my preferences for *Export*[image].

I tried Export with ***Simplify 0.1***. I also tried turning off the ***Stretch To*** constraint and IK Stretch, but that didn't work either.

Here is [*.Blend*](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Jng_EfBOkTbkMHaNX-4ZRlOrYIowtHR7/view?usp=sharing) file with some references.

Comment: It's not clear what the problem is. Also why did you try flat hierarchy? The first image looks ok...

Comment: Finaly!I found a solution to the problem, but I don't know if it's a crutch or not. After use the RigifyToUnity addon I turned off all constraints on DEF- bones and use Copy Transform constraints from ORG- to DEF- bones and.... all works